# JavaFX 2 define onChange listener in FXML

Tags: onchange, javafx-2, fxml

I am busy teaching myself FXML.
I'm doing this by following [this](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-03-2012/120306-practical-javafx2-2.html?page=6) example.

It's a simple text editor.
However, in the tutorial everything is Java code.

I myself am using FXML to seperate the view of the logic.

I currently face the following challenge:

I have defined an TextArea in my FXML like so:

```
<TextArea id="taTextArea" fx:id="taContent" wrapText="true" />
```

Usually you add action listeners using onAction="#actionName"

What I want to know is, how can I do something similar for text changes. So I can detect wether a save is needed, modify the status bar label etc.

I want to avoid having to attach the TextArea to a change listener in the init method of the controller(implementing Initializable).

Also.. when I complete this application, I will write a blog about it.
With the lacking FXML documentation, I think itll be helpfull to other newbies.
So I want my code to be as clean as possible.

### EDIT 1

No progress yet. I need to know if theres a thing such as code completion in FXML
So I can check what kind of properties I can use in FXMl. There should be a textLength property. In the provided link the author uses lengthProperty.addListener. I need an FXML equivilant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the onKeyPressed property:

```
onKeyPressed="#textChanged"
```

which calls the textChanged method in the specified controller.

For the second question: The best reference for FXML currently is the javadoc of JavaFX, since all properties are listed there.

Comment: Thanks alot. This deffinetly answers the question. However Im facing a similar question with the next part in the example. listening to text selection. How would I go about this? in the example a proeprty is used. Can I call that in fxml? can I attach an event to the property through fxml? if fxml uses the same proeprties(logically) as plain java it should be possible..

Comment: that depends. What do you want to do with the selection? In FXML, you can bind to the selectedText property of the TextArea like this: <Label text="${taTextArea.selectedText}"/>
Since there is not something like an onChanged property in Observable or similar, i don't think it is possible to add an arbitrary listener to a property via FXML.